# Using cameraController.cameraOverlayView versus cameraController.view

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, appstore-approval, cameraoverlayview

Say you bring up the camera on an iPhone:

```
self.cameraController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:self.cameraController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

It's easy enough to add a button to that.  But interesting you can do **THIS**:

```
UIView *examp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley"]];
[self.cameraController.view addSubview:examp];
```

**OR THIS**

```
UIView *examp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley"]];
self.cameraController.cameraOverlayView = examp;
```

They both work perfectly in testing.

However will often see it mentioned that if you change anything, other than using camera.OverlayView, Apple will reject it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

As a curiosity, in fact has anyone ever **had an app rejected** when adding a subview to the .view? Any insights?